# Theorem about embeddings of a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Can you give me a reference* for the following theorem:

> Let $\mathbb{Q} \subset K\subset \mathbb{C}$ be an algebraic number field and $\alpha \in K$. If $\sigma(\alpha) = \alpha$ for all $\sigma \in \mathrm{Hom}(K, \mathbb{C})$, then $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}$.

And:

> The number of embeddings of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ in $\mathbb{C}$ equals the degree of $\alpha$.

Thank you!

*this means a book where I can find these theorems.

Answer (score 1):

An embedding of $K$ in $\mathbf C$ maps $\alpha$ onto a root of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$, and conversely, mapping $\alpha$ onto a root  of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ defines a $\mathbf Q$-homomorphism of $\mathbf Q(\alpha)$ into $\mathbf C$ (map $\mathbf Q[x]$ into $\mathbf C$ first  and check the kernel is generated by the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$).

Hence if $\sigma(\alpha)=\alpha$  for all  $\sigma\in \operatorname{Hom}(K,\mathbf C)$, the only root of the minimal polynomial is $\alpha$, and it is a simple root, since we're in characteristic $0$, which proves the minimal polynomial has degree $1$ — in other words, $\alpha \in\mathbf Q$.This also proves the second assertion.

Comment: Thank you, but that's not really what I asked. ;-) Do you know a book or other reference where I can find these or similar theorems?

Comment: Looks like I found a reference for the second theorem: Proposition 3.1.12 in *Number Theory: Volume I* by Henri Cohen.

Comment: @aRaRa: I think I gave hints for your question: is $\sigma(\alpha)=\alpha$ for all $\sigma\in\operatorname{Hom}(K, \mathbf C)$ the $\alpha \in \mathbf Q$. What do you mean with ‘that's not really what I asked’?

Comment: Because the question is not "how do I prove these theorems" but "where do I find these theorems".